# Unnest complex pyspark schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I need help in unnesting dataframe in a specific format.

The data is a bit complex as below -

```
[{
    "ItemType": "CONSTRUCTION",
    "ItemId": "9169-bd62eac18e73",
    "Content": {
        "MetadataSetList": [
            {
                "SetId": "privacy-metadata-set",
                "MetadataList": [
                    {
                        "MetadataValue": "true",
                        "MetadataId": "Public"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "SetId": "asset-metadata-set",
                "MetadataList": [
                    {
                        "MetadataValue": "new upload & edit test",
                        "MetadataId": "title"
                    },
                    {
                        "MetadataValue": "someone",
                        "MetadataId": "uploader"
                    },
                    {
                        "MetadataValue": "One,Five",
                        "MetadataId": "Families"
                    },
                    {
                        "MetadataValue": "@xyzzzzz",
                        "MetadataId": "creator"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "MetadataType": "UNDER CONSTRUCTION",
        "Tenant": "8ef4-0e976f342606"
    },
    "Version":"1.0",
    "IsActive":False,
    "Status":"DEPRECATED"
}]
```

My requirement is to modify the above record such that, the data within "Content" is unnested where value of "MetadataId" is the new key and the value of "MetadataValue" is value for that new key.Something similar as below --

```
[
        {
            "status": "DEPRECATED",
            "version": "1.0",
            "item_type": "CONSTRUCTION",
            "item_id": "9169-bd62eac18e73",
            "is_active":False,
            "content": {
                "Public": "true", 
                "title": "new upload & edit test",
                "uploader": "someone",
                "Families": "One,Five",
                "creator": "@xyzzzzz"
            },
            "metadata_type": "UNDER CONSTRUCTION",
            "tenant": "8ef4-0e976f342606"
        }
    ]
```

I had the below code to transform the data in python script-

```
#Data Transformation Function
def transform_data(docs):
    """

    """
    unnested_table_items = []

    for doc in docs:
        NewDoc = {}

        NewDoc['status'] = doc['Status']
        NewDoc['version'] = doc['Version']
        NewDoc['item_type'] = doc['ItemType']
        NewDoc['item_id'] = doc['ItemId']
        NewDoc['is_active'] = doc['IsActive']
        content_dict = {}
        for row in doc['Content']['MetadataSetList']:
            for _ in row['MetadataList']:
                k = _['MetadataId']
                v = _['MetadataValue']
                content_dict.update({k: v})

        NewDoc['content'] = content_dict
        NewDoc['metadata_type'] = doc['Content']['MetadataType']
        NewDoc['tenant'] = doc['Content']['Tenant']

        unnested_table_items.append(NewDoc)

    return unnested_table_items
```

Now the data stored in S3 and I need to use AWS Glue. When I creating the DynamicFrame reading the data from S3, the Schema structure is

```
root
|-- ItemType: string
|-- ItemId: string
|-- Content: struct
|    |-- MetadataSetList: array
|    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |-- SetId: string
|    |    |    |-- MetadataList: array
|    |    |    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |-- MetadataValue: string
|    |    |    |    |    |-- MetadataId: string
|    |-- MetadataType: string
|    |-- Tenant: string
|-- Version: string
|-- IsActive: string
|-- Status: string
```

```
+------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------+----------+
|ItemType    |ItemId           |Content                                                                                                                                                                                                     |Version|IsActive|Status    |
+------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------+----------+
|CONSTRUCTION|9169-bd62eac18e73|[[[privacy-metadata-set, [[true, Public]]], [asset-metadata-set, [[new upload & edit test, title], [someone, uploader], [One,Five, Families], [@xyzzzzz, creator]]]], UNDER CONSTRUCTION, 8ef4-0e976f342606]|1.0    |False   |DEPRECATED|
+------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

With this schema struture how can I transform it to get the data as shown post python function transformation.

Kindly suggest.Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to solve using scala, but all the `functions` used are there in pyspark apis-

### 1. Load the data

```scala
  val data =
      """
        |[{
        |    "ItemType": "CONSTRUCTION",
        |    "ItemId": "9169-bd62eac18e73",
        |    "Content": {
        |        "MetadataSetList": [
        |            {
        |                "SetId": "privacy-metadata-set",
        |                "MetadataList": [
        |                    {
        |                        "MetadataValue": "true",
        |                        "MetadataId": "Public"
        |                    }
        |                ]
        |            },
        |            {
        |                "SetId": "asset-metadata-set",
        |                "MetadataList": [
        |                    {
        |                        "MetadataValue": "new upload & edit test",
        |                        "MetadataId": "title"
        |                    },
        |                    {
        |                        "MetadataValue": "someone",
        |                        "MetadataId": "uploader"
        |                    },
        |                    {
        |                        "MetadataValue": "One,Five",
        |                        "MetadataId": "Families"
        |                    },
        |                    {
        |                        "MetadataValue": "@xyzzzzz",
        |                        "MetadataId": "creator"
        |                    }
        |                ]
        |            }
        |        ],
        |        "MetadataType": "UNDER CONSTRUCTION",
        |        "Tenant": "8ef4-0e976f342606"
        |    },
        |    "Version":"1.0",
        |    "IsActive":false,
        |    "Status":"DEPRECATED"
        |}]
      """.stripMargin

    val df = spark.read
      .option("multiline", true)
      .json(Seq(data).toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+
      * |Content                                                                                                                                                                                                     |IsActive|ItemId           |ItemType    |Status    |Version|
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+
      * |[[[[[Public, true]], privacy-metadata-set], [[[title, new upload & edit test], [uploader, someone], [Families, One,Five], [creator, @xyzzzzz]], asset-metadata-set]], UNDER CONSTRUCTION, 8ef4-0e976f342606]|false   |9169-bd62eac18e73|CONSTRUCTION|DEPRECATED|1.0    |
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Content: struct (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- MetadataSetList: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |    |-- MetadataList: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |    |    |    |-- MetadataId: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |    |    |    |-- MetadataValue: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |    |-- SetId: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- MetadataType: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- Tenant: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- IsActive: boolean (nullable = true)
      * |-- ItemId: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- ItemType: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Status: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Version: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### 2. Processe the data

```scala
     val mergeMap = udf((arr: mutable.WrappedArray[Map[String, String]]) => {
        val res = mutable.HashMap.empty[String, String]
        arr.foldLeft(res){case (map, next) => next.++:(map)(collection.breakOut)}
      })

   val processedDF = df.select(col("IsActive").as("is_active"),
      col("ItemId").as("item_id"),
      col("ItemType").as("item_type"),
      col("Status").as("status"),
      col("Version").as("version"),
      col("Content.MetadataType").as("metadata_type"),
      col("Content.Tenant").as("tenant"),
      col("Content.MetadataSetList").getItem(0).getField("MetadataList").as("content1"),
      col("Content.MetadataSetList").getItem(1).getField("MetadataList").as("content2")
    ).withColumn("content",
      array_union(
        col("content1"),
        col("content2")
      )
    )
      .withColumn("content", expr("TRANSFORM(content, x -> map(x.MetadataId, x.MetadataValue))"))
     .withColumn("content", mergeMap(col("content")))
      .drop("content1", "content2")

    processedDF.show(false)
    processedDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |is_active|item_id          |item_type   |status    |version|metadata_type     |tenant           |content                                                                                                          |
      * +---------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |false    |9169-bd62eac18e73|CONSTRUCTION|DEPRECATED|1.0    |UNDER CONSTRUCTION|8ef4-0e976f342606|[Families -> One,Five, Public -> true, creator -> @xyzzzzz, title -> new upload & edit test, uploader -> someone]|
      * +---------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- is_active: boolean (nullable = true)
      * |-- item_id: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- item_type: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- status: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- version: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- metadata_type: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- tenant: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- content: map (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
      */
```

### 3. converting dataframe to json

```scala
    processedDF.toJSON
      .show(false)

//    {
//      "is_active": false,
//      "item_id": "9169-bd62eac18e73",
//      "item_type": "CONSTRUCTION",
//      "status": "DEPRECATED",
//      "version": "1.0",
//      "metadata_type": "UNDER CONSTRUCTION",
//      "tenant": "8ef4-0e976f342606",
//      "content": {
//        "Public": "true",
//        "Families": "One,Five",
//        "creator": "@xyzzzzz",
//        "uploader": "someone",
//        "title": "new upload & edit test"
//      }
//    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Someshwar for your help. I ended up creating UDF for the transformation.

```
        def content_transform(x):

            content_dict = {}
            for row in x:
                for _ in row['MetadataList']:
                    k = _['MetadataId']
                    v = _['MetadataValue']
                    content_dict.update({k: v})

            return str(content_dict)

        def content_udf():
            return functions.udf(content_transform, types.StringType())

        df2 = (df1
               .withColumn("ContentUnnested", content_udf()
                           (functions.col("Content.MetadataSetList"))))
```

After converting it into StringType, I used [Unbox class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-Unbox.html) from AWS Glue to unbox in json.